# Couldn't display YOLO result via OpenCV dnn module

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to train YOLO object detection via darknet([AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) or [pjreddie](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet)) and it was great for showing object via

`./darknet detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolo-obj.cfg yolo.weights data/test.jpg`

I used 160*30 images for training and testing. Also I did it via Tiny-YOLOv2 and another model and it could detect all numbers in the images.

But when I want to showing result for trained weight and a specific image like bellow, and by using Opencv  dnn modules, I could not display all objects(numbers) correctly.

[YOLO Object Detection with OpenCV and Python](https://www.arunponnusamy.com/yolo-object-detection-opencv-python.html)

[Deep Learning based Object Detection using YOLOv3 with OpenCV ( Python / C++)](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/)

[YOLO object detection with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/)

[YOLO object detection using OpenCV and Python](https://pysource.com/2019/06/27/yolo-object-detection-using-opencv-with-python/)

[Exploring OpenCV’s Deep Learning Object Detection Library](https://medium.com/@franky07724_57962/exploring-opencvs-deep-learning-object-detection-library-e51fe7c82246)

But when I check it for a bigger image(1280*760), It could show results.

[image: Input Image]

correct output for plate detection:
[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. When we want to show the result using OpenCV and DNN module, we must consider the resizing ratio of the original image. For example when I have an `160*30` input image, at first I convert it to `416*78`(resizing one of the width or height to 416). Now for showing results, I resize height by multiplying it to `416/78`